# How do you add jsonb functions in FROM subqueries using JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

How do you build this query using jooq?

```
select et.id 
from t, et, 
    jsonb_array_elements(t.keys_and_values) as s, jsonb_object_keys(s) as s1
where et.id = t.id
and s1 = 'key'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you're missing API support for vendor specific SQL features, you can resort to using the [plain SQL templating API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/). I.e. write

```
Table<?> s = DSL.table("jsonb_array_elements({0})", T.KEYS_AND_VALUES).as("s");
Table<?> s1 = DSL.table("jsonb_object_keys({0})", s).as("s1");
```

And then, in order to form a predicate, you can write:

```
DSL.condition("{0} = {1}", s1, DSL.val("key"));
```

There are many other approaches, all using the plain SQL templating API, depending on how much you want to reuse some vendor specific function expressions, etc.